# HTTPS Issue With Mixed Content - ARForms Plugin

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I have a site wordpress in HTTPS, but also i have an Mixed Content because of ARForms Plugin. PHP 5.6
fonts.googleapis.com and some images in this plugin unsecure, and that files i cant find in database anf template files, please help me by PHP.
Thank you.
This is what i found in configuration and this functional not work:

```
$arfsiteurl = home_url();
if (is_ssl() and ( !preg_match('/^https:\/\/.*\..*$/', $arfsiteurl) or ! preg_match('/^https:\/\/.*\..*$/', WP_PLUGIN_URL))) {
    $arfsiteurl = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $arfsiteurl);
    define('ARFURL', str_replace('http://', 'https://', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/arforms'));
} else {
    define('ARFURL', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/arforms');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to download these scripts locally and enqueue them with your HTTPS secure server.

As for the plugin scripts, you could also try to install [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/) plugin and click the flush rewrite rules for it to automatically add code into your .htaccess file.